# Why clipping not working

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple mesh. To the mesh i have mirror modifier and curve modifier. With the clipping option on. I want to extrude the gap between so that they attach to each other. But they do not.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help why clipping option not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because when you move this part of your mesh in order to close your ring, you actually move it in the -X direction, which is away form the X axis (your *Mirror* axis). So I guess you have no other choice than apply the *Curve* modifier, then it will clip correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but I think it's your topology that's messing up the clipping since merge is also enabled. I tried to clip the upper part and the lower part together and the lower part seems to clip at upper part for some reason.

[image]

I really don't know anything about curves but seems like the origin is set to top by default?